# Convert SHA1 Cert to MD5 Using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, md5, sha1

I'm trying to convert servers from http to https, and I am having trouble because of problematic certs residing in the keystore:

My end goal is to automate a process to programmatically go through these certs in the keystore and convert them to a different format (i.e. MD5). **Is there a command that can simply convert SHA1 --> MD5?** Is that even possible?

Is there an easier way than going through OpenSSL? I'm sorry if this question was phrased badly, I have a very limited understanding of this subject matter.

Thank you!

Comment: Once signed by the CA, the certificates can't be altered or "converted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugene's comment correctly points out the answer is almost certainly no. This is because certificates are more complicated than a mere collection of fields. Certificates are signed by a certificate authority. This signature acts as a kind of secure checksum which cannot be tampered with. If you change even one bit of the certificate the signature will fail to verify.

There is one special case in which you *can* do this that probably does not apply to your case: if your certificates are self-signed.